# Basic SQL - What’s best possible answer if you know ?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, you have a Customer table and an Order table.  The relationship between the two tables is the CustomerId field.  It’s a foreign key from the Orders back to the primary table Customer.  With that in mind, how would you write a query that would retrieve Customers that don’t have Orders.

Comment: Hint: LEFT JOIN with WHERE customer.column IS NULL or NOT EXISTS

Comment: Or even better, since you just want customer information, just a `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders)`

Comment: Honestly, this really sounds like a homework problem in the AdventureWorks database. Please share what you've tried so far, what is your specific problem, what are the results of your research. Please read [ask] in [help] for further info.

Comment: The concept you're interested in is called an _anti-semi-join_, which, as Raymond mentioned, is implemented using `NOT EXISTS`. Read [this introduction to joins](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/07/19/introduction-to-joins/), which happens to use the same table relationship (customers and sales) as your question.

Comment: Great and thanks to everyone for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will return all customers on the left of the query and will show a NULL on the right where there are no matching order records.
We then filter to only show those with NULL in the right table.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Customers c
       LEFT JOIN Orders o
           ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId 
WHERE  o.CustomerId IS NULL
```

Below is a great diagram explaining the different types of join

[image]